# I want datetimepicker.mindate < datetimepicker1.value

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

i am doing the below:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(comboBox3.Text); // -> contains a date value converted to string

dateTimePicker1.MinDate < dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

The goal is to take any value that is less than the `dateTimePicker1.Value` and set it as `MinDate` that way all the date before the `dateTimePicker1.Value` are greyed out.

the end result should look something like this:

The error i get is:

> Error  1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

any help with this will be much appreciated thanks guys!!!!!

Comment: _"the end result should look something like this:"_ then comes the error

Comment: x < y;   ... is not a statement.

Comment: i wanted to show a pic but the website said something about me needing 7 reputations to do that, datetimepicker contains the value of the combobox right, so why not set anything less than that to be a MinDate?? i am able to achieve the result by this:                                          dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Parse(comboBox3.Text); but it is very slow for each time comboBox3.text changes the datetimepicker either freezes or does change to the newest value. Does anyone this  loops will be handy in achieving the result??

Comment: @Dmitry ,Tim Schmelter, Holger, SilentKiller, EdChum so this is closed as unclear on what im asking. All i said above was i want to grey out max and min date that i am getting from a comboBox. but someone answered exactly what i needed, so who is unclear now????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception is telling you that have to give dateTimePicker1 a value. Also, the order you do things is important. You can't set dateTimePicker1's value to less than the MinDate. That's the purpose of having a MinDate. You must first modify the MinDate, then set the value.

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Parse(comboBox3.Text); // -> contains a date value converted to string
dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.MinDate
```

Comment: your the man!!!! exactly what i was looking for!! so it sets the min date first and then takes that value as the datetimepicker.value, now i realize the importance of order :) Thanks a lot!!!!!